How do chores fit in with positive discipline?
My boys are still young (2.75 and 4.5), and they do a lot of natural helping, so I'm not entirely sure if they're ready for firm, consistent responsibilities yet, but I'm interested to know how best to make this work with positive discipline, and what age is appropriate to get chores started.
At the moment we don't force them to do any particular thing unless they've made a mess in an obvious, anti-social way. Occasionally they'll help us clean up, occasionally they say no and we clean up, for the most part we don't make a big deal about it unless it's a behavior that needs correcting.
So with positive discipline I'm interested in understanding what the most appropriate way is to make this non-dramatic approach work when they're older and they refuse to do some of their chores. My wife and I are both agreed that we don't want to tie their chores to an allowance, because cleaning and organizing is just a part of life that they need to learn.
But that leads to the question of: what exactly do we do in response to the situation where they aren't doing their chores or fulfilling some of their responsibilities? We don't want to punish them in a hurtful way, or force them, but we do want to teach them personal responsibility. So what would be an appropriate way to encourage fulfilling their responsibilities without negative reinforcement?

The simple answer is to "catch your child being good", i.e. reward the child from very early on when they do help, whether it's a chore or not. Starting early and identifying help (recognizing the value of an empathetic response to seeing someone laboring) goes a long way in framing chores positively later on.
Like everything in positive parenting, starting early and being consistent pays off for the extra time it takes to catch a child being good. Rewards can be as simple as affirmation or can include extra time/attention. It stands to reason that if a child saves you a bit of time doing a chore (we called it "family service"), then you have more time to give to the child. Although it might be seen as transactional, I also used sticker charts to work on creating positive attitudes, and a certain amount of stickers could be traded in for the reward, e.g. spending time with my child doing something they enjoyed that required parental involvement, at first as simple as playing a game with them, reading them a story, etc. or sitting together enjoying ice cream and a conversation. This is in addition to normal positive interactions, not in place of.*
If they don't do their chore, spend time finding out why that is. Is it something they hate? Trade chores, or tailor chores to temperament, or evaluate the need for the chore, or... or... Have regular discussions as a family about what things need to get done and why. At the same time, getting input from the child and giving it real consideration reinforces the concept of families working together. That, too, pays off in time not spent needing to lecture kids on their responsibilities, seeing as they already agreed, for example, that animals they like need to be fed and cleaned up after. The time to discuss responsibility isn't after they fail, it's long before they start.
Finally, negative consequences are natural. You can't shield a child from the negative. Life isn't fair, and that was abundantly clear early on, especially as we were a 'medical family' (both parents in the health care field; accidents and other bad things happen.) Helping a child early on with coping skills (e.g. living with unfulfilled expectations) is important when pondering future struggles.
*One of my kids happened to love mazes and myths (no apparent relationship) so for reaching a desired small goal, I would ask, "Would you like a myth or a maze?" Mazes help with frustration and feeling successful, while myths were fun for me to read, too. Plus, they got a great background early on in Greek and Norse mythology. 
Chores and Children
The longer I live, the less I am certain about how to parent "correctly". I still think positive parenting is best, but I'm less certain. Life isn't fair, and I've seen a lot of "failure" among kids who were parented pretty positively. Just recently I found some old photos of my kids with some good friends, and was startled to realize that of this one photo, two of the kids in this smallish group had already died, one by suicide, and the other under mysterious circumstances following a decade of total estrangement from family. There is nature and there is nurture. Respect both and do the best you can. The rest is out of your hands.

Thanks for the answer. In your estimation what would be a good indicator that we can begin 'official' duties?

Start early enough that they can't remember a time that they didn't have chores. Your eldest can be doing a few easy ones like setting the table (with inexpensive tableware). Feel him out in discussions about family responsibility, outlining yours simply and asking for suggestions a few he thinks he could. It takes much more time than doing it yourself, but without chores, they won't learn about responsibility or get satisfaction from being a helpful family member. The indication? They're coordinated enough to do them and they enjoy your sincere gratitude (and the rewards!)

Thanks for the explanation, unfortunately I think the older one has already discovered the power of just saying no to things, or asking mom and dad to do it. With tasks he can and wants to do himself we mostly refuse now, but helping is definitely much more selective on the mood of the moment. Which.. honestly, fair enough, as my wife and I approach chores the same way (we do them when we want to). I'll have to do some thinking on this.

@Cdn_Dev - It's definitely a challenge with much trading off. This is where 1) having a discussion ahead of time really pays off, and 2) modeling the desired behavior. If you do chores only when you want to, the child will choose that, too. Finding out why they say no, and trading chores is fair, too. We do it; if I didn't feel like cooking, we ordered pizza. I traded money for "time off". Incentives help, too; movie night doesn't start until chores are all done (and if not done, the time for movies has passed.) It's easier when both spouses agree, a situation we  didn't enjoy. :(

Also, we had animals, a lot of them, everything from milk goats to peacocks to ducks and quail. They require food and fresh water every day. The goats needed to be milked and eggs needed to be collected, whether one feels like supplying it or not. Animals are a true responsibility. Like employment for responsible adults. Even now, I don't know if it was absolutely the right thing...  One of my kids hated to work. Parenting isn't easy.

Speaking as someone who had a (maybe surprising for some) positive experience growing up with spankings, the three things that made the discipline effective (and not traumatizing) is that my parents 1. never disciplined in anger, 2. were VERY consistent with how and why discipline was applied and 3. made sure I understood the cause and effect before applying discipline. Their consistency made the discipline feel like a "safe" part of my environment (a boundary) rather than an unpredictable emotional reaction, and was a good proxy for grasping how my actions affect those around me.

@Blackhawk - The positivity you wrote of is inconsistent with Positive Parenting. The experience you describe is very common in certain circles with with I am very familiar. There's a lot I can say about it that might be critical if I knew a bit more; I'm glad I don't, because in those circles with which I'm familiar, it's very destructive. Spanking is punishment, not discipline. There is no spanking in positive parenting. Discipline is meant to teach; spanking is meant to hurt (whether it did or not.) The fact that it's meant to hurt demeans to a child.

@anongoodnurse I apologize - I meant to emphasize the 3 points on my parents' thoughtful approach to discipline and not the spanking in particular. My point is that IF the OP were to incorporate discipline as you alluded to in the small print, then (based on my experience) being careful about their approach in those 3 aspects can avoid some of the typical negatives associated with discipline.

@Blackhawk - Ah, understood. Thanks for clarifying! I agree with the spirit (and the letter) of the three points. :)

I'm not a parent but grew up in a family of 5 kids.  My suggestion applies to older kids.
In my family a common root conflict was our parents wanting us to do what they felt was right which was at odds with how we felt.  And often their answer was we were wrong and had to do what they wanted.  In movies, t.v. shows etc. this seems pretty standard.  Kids do what their parents say because their parents said so.
I think this works because it's simple.  However it also creates more conflict than necessary.  Growing up I remember having a lot of disagreements and anger toward my parents due to this.
My opinion is that parents should have much more a discussion surrounding behavior they want changed and be ready to compromise and figure out what can work for everyone.  The discussion should center around their goal and what everyone can do to reach it.  A compromise would be changing that goal to be something everyone can work with.
Kids don't have the choice of where to live, who to live with and how.  Parents are the ones who chose to have kids - and forcing them to do things that don't make sense to them is potentially harmful to the family relationship.
Obviously this is an enormous gray area. Kids will think wild things and reason or discussion won't always work.  However I think reason, discussion and compromise are left behind more than they should be.  Likely and sadly, because it is more time consuming and complicated.

When I was growing up chores were a fact of life. They teach not just discipline (rewards when completed properly, maybe mild punishment if not done (but the lack of reward was punishment in and of itself)), but also useful skills.
Helping my mother in the kitchen taught me how to cook (simple things at first, more complex things as I grew older) and how to organise the pantry and fridge for example. I also learned how to iron clothes (not that I ever liked doing THAT, I still hate it), fold them, and stock them in the closet.
In the garden we took care of the animals, weeding flower beds, etc. etc. Both fun and useful skills.
To this date however I have trouble cleaning floors and windows as my mother NEVER let us do that.

I agree with you about the need to do them and the benefits, but the question is specifically how handle chores in the context of positive parenting, which means no punishments (lack of a reward is not the same as punishment.) Sounds like you did well and it's a good list!

@anongoodnurse without a different outcome depending on whether the chores are performed or not, they may as well not be there at all. It's no different from adult life, or school. Don't do your work and you don't get paid (or don't get a passing grade). Positive parenting shouldn't be about there being no consequences for bad behaviour, but about reinforcing good behaviour.

Maybe you're confused about my comment, or about positive parenting?Consequences (and responsibility) are definitely part of positive parenting; punishment is not. I don't think your answer really pertains to chores and Positive Parenting. Mostly it's just a list of chores. A good list, but nothing particular about PP, as stated before.
